# how to delete duplicate number from row?

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, grep

**Input file**

```
1 2 3 1 4 5 6 1 1 2 34 5 6 2
```

I want **output** like this

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 34
```

( all the duplicate number should print only once )

Comment: Can the output be sorted, or does it have to keep the same order?

Comment: Can you please clarify your Q? It's unclear whether sorting the results is OK or not. You have both types of A'ers ATM.

Comment: Does your input always consist of a single line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` (***to remove duplicates from whole file***):

```
awk '{ SEP=""; i=0;  
       while (++i<=NF) { printf (!unq[$i]++? SEP $i:""); SEP=" "};
       print "";
}' infile
```

***or remove duplicates from each line separately***:

```
awk '{ SEP=""; i=0; delete unq;
       while (++i<=NF) { printf (!unq[$i]++? SEP $i:""); SEP=" "};
       print "";
}' infile
```

Loop over numbers and if it was not previously seen, add it to the array called `unq` and `printf` it else print nothing.

#### future reading:

- [How can I numerically sort a single line of delimited items?](/q/436102/72456)

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lane 'print join " ", grep ! $seen{$_}++, @F' < file
```

- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output
- `-n` processes the input line by line
- `-a` splits each input on whitespace into the @F array

The @F array is iterated over by [grep](http://p3rl.org/grep), keeping only the elements that are seen for the first time (i.e. their value in the %seen hash are zero, as a negation of zero is true). [join](http://p3rl.org/join) just glues them back together.

Comment: ... or `perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -alne 'print join " ", uniq @F'`

Comment: @steeldriver: [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util) now provides `uniq`, too.

Comment: Ah thanks - I thought it did but I was testing on an old box with 5.22

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** *This solution keeps the results in their original order!*

---

Easy way to do this using `awk` and `tr`. If your content is in a file, `FILE`:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < FILE | awk '!x[$0]++' | tr '\n' ' '
```

#### Example

```
$ echo "1 2 3 1 4 5 6 1 1 2 34 5 6 2" | \
    tr ' ' '\n' | awk '!x[$0]++' | tr '\n' ' '
1 2 3 4 5 6 34
```

#### How it works

- `tr ' ' '\n'` - switches spaces to newlines
- `awk '!x[$0]++'` - prints characters that do not repeat
- `tr '\n' ' '` - switches newlines back to spaces

Comment: This assumes that the input is always a single line, right? That's what the OP described in the question, but it is not clear to me that that was the intent.

Comment: @NickD - This can deal with the data both ways. I agree though, that the OP needs to clarify several questions that many of us have either assumed or didn't realize to ask.

Comment: Don't need `tr` just `awk -vRS='[ \n]' -vORS=' ' '!x[$0]++'` and optionally add `;END{printf "\n"}` if you want a well-formed line out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr`, `awk` or `sed` to get all numbers in separate line, then use `sort` and `uniq` to remove duplicate entries

Example with **tr**:

```
$ tr " " "\n"  < <INPUT-FILE> | sort -u | tr "\n" " "
```

Comment: The redir was intentional 8-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `sort`. Sort only operates on rows so you need to replace the spaces in your file with new lines.

Example if file `test.txt` contains:

```
 1 2 3 1 4 5 6 1 1 2 34 5 6 2
```

The following code will return what you want

```
>sed "s/ /\n/g" test.txt | sort -un
1
2
3
4
5
6
34
```

Note that while `sort -u` will return "unique" (non-duplicated values), the are ordered alphabetically unless you sort numerically with `sort -n`. Sort is necessary here as `uniq` only removes consecutive duplicates so you would need to pipe `sort -n | uniq` and `sort` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Unix style way of accomplishing this is to use the basic core utilities and pipe the contents of test.txt to the appropriate program rather than use a full-blown scripting language, like so:

```
$ cat test.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Nice. Same concept with different utilities (requires bash): `(set -f; printf "%s\n" $(<file) | sort -un | paste -sd " ")`

Comment: As of late, since I've been experimenting with various flavors of BSD, I try to avoid using bashisms unless necessary. After all, why add an additional dependency if it's not necessary. (See Also: Shellshock)

Answer (score 0):

In bash : Preserves the reading order. Reads several lines in the file. Returns a single line.

```
 unset d
 while read r; do
  [ "$d" ] || d=${r/ */}
  for s in $r; do
    for s2 in $d; do
      if [ "$s" = $s2 ]; then
        s=
        break
      fi
    done
    d="$d $s"
  done
done < file
echo ${d}
unset d r s s2
```

A script is better

```
echo '
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# = 0 ]; then
  echo "${0##*/} <filepath>" >&2
  exit
elif [ ! -f $1 ]; then
  echo " Error : $1 is not a file." >&2
  exit 1
fi

while read r; do
  [ "$d" ] || d=${r/ */}
  for s in $r; do
    for s2 in $d; do
      if [ "$s" = $s2 ]; then
        s=
        break
      fi
    done
    d="$d $s"
  done
done < $1
echo ${d}
' > ~/uniq-word
```

For use it :

```
bash ~/uniq-word <filepath>
```